# Connectedness and locally path-connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm studying algebraic topology and I have this doubt:

> $X$ is a topological space connected and locally path-connected; does this imply that $X$ is path-connected ? Why ?

Meaning of locally path-connected: every point $p \in X $ has a path-connected neighbourhood.

Comment: This is **not** what locally path connected means! Otherwise every path connected space would be locally path connected. Consider the space $\mathbb{Q} \times [0,1] / \mathbb{Q} \times \{1\}$ for example... A space is locally path connected if every point has a **basis** of path connected neighborhoods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
Fix $a \in X$ and consider the set
$$U = \{ x \in X | \mbox{ there exists a path connecting $a$ and $x$ } \}$$

Try to show that $U$ is both closed and open.